# How to auto close the console in BlueJ

Tags: java, console, exit

I want to exit only the console in a method.

I tried this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Press Enter to quit...");
input.nextLine();
```

and now I want only to end the console, I tried `System.exit(0);`, but this only "deletes" the object and the console stays. Is there any other command I can use?

*I'm using BlueJ for a school project and there we have the console that appears with* `System.out.println()`*, this console I want to close... I know you can click on the* `X` *of the console window, but I want to do it automatically in the method when you click enter for example*

Comment: You don't need to "end the console". In fact don't call close on a `Scanner` opened on `System.in`. If you're talking about the 'black window' your Java is running in, your app has no control over that

Comment: @g00se
No I'm using BlueJ for a school project and there we have the console that appears with ```System.out.println()```, this console I want to close...
I know you can click on the `X` of the console window, but I want to do it automatically in the method when you click enter for example

Comment: If you're using Windows you can create a shortcut to your app to use `javaw.exe` and the console *will* close with the code you have now. Other OS consoles can probably be made to close too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

No, your Java app cannot control the outer shell app running in a console. Indeed, it makes no sense for your Java app to *want* to manipulate or kill that console.

### Details

The console, where text appears and where the user types, is always under the control of another app, not your Java app.

To invoke a non-GUI Java app, you need to already be using a console. That console exists before your Java app runs. And that console exists after your Java app runs. Indeed, the console reports the ultimate result of your Java app — like any console app, your Java app reports an [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), an integer number generated as it exits. The exit code indicate whether the app ran successfully or not. For example:

> Process finished with exit code 0

The “outer” app providing the console can be:

- A [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) program within console software running via a [computer terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) (in the old days)
- A shell program within a console running within a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Emulation) app such as [*Terminal.app*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) on macOS.
- A shell program running within a console within a [window pane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paned_window_(computing)) of an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

That last describes your situation in [BlueJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueJ). BlueJ is a specialized IDE that hides much of the elaborate ceremony involved in Java programming.

But the basic idea is the same: When you run your Java app, BlueJ constructs a console within its own application windowing, runs some kind of shell within that console, and executes your Java app. BlueJ is designed to hide the nitty-gritty details from you as a beginning student, but the actions underneath are essentially the same.

You can think of a computer as concentric circles:

- In the core middle is the [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit).
- A ring outside that is the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).
- A further ring is a console app to interface with a human.
- Next ring out is a shell app run by that console, such as [*zsh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), [*bash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), etc. The shell provides for convenient interactions with the human through a [command-line interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). A shell is actually an app within the console; the human user can exit one shell and start another such as switching from *bash* to *zsh*.
- Another ring outside that is any app invoked on the command-line interface of the shell. For example, the [*java*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html) [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (“command”) to run a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), inside of which your Java code executes. Eventually your Java app ends, and the *java* command exits, returning an exit code to the shell app.
- Optionally, a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) can launch such as seen on a Mac, MS Windows, or Linux/BSD desktop computer. You can think of this as yet another outer ring. You can see GUI computers running the console during boot-up, showing console activity either by default or by alternate booting scenario.

The point is: The console & **shell app exist before, during, and after your Java app** execution.

In your case, BlueJ is constructing that console & shell, and maintaining it before and after your Java app runs. So your Java app has no control over the creation/destruction of the console & shell.

---

By the way, the Java team at Oracle, and the Java community, have been working on providing easier on-ramps for people new to Java.

- [*JShell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JShell)
- [*JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330)
- [*JEP 445: Unnamed Classes and Instance Main Methods (Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/445)

Comment: Thanks, for the long but understandable answer! And now I understand that I can't do it. Thanks again..